# Clicking outside the "share a link to this question" popup should close it

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

When the "share a link to this question" popup is displayed, pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button closes it.
Clicking on a "regular" place on the page should have the same effect.

Comment: Agreed.  Clicking elsewhere currently deselects the link, making the box completely useless and obscuring the top comments.

Answer (score 3):

I definitely agree — current behavior is non-intuitive as the policy in most applications which have some form of pop-up window (and this is definitely in that class of UI devices), will either move the pop-up to the background if a larger window gains focus or it will refuse to let the user continue until the window has been acknowledged.

This is not something which demands mandatory focus (such as an alert or a prompt), it follows that it should hide (or, in this case, go away) when it loses focus.

Besides, that's how Facebook pictures work, and if it is good enough for Facebook, it is good enough for here! (::ducks to avoid the inevitable thrown shoe::)

Comment: Wow, that first sentence is not technically a run-on, but it certainly does its share of verbal gymnastics.

Comment: the shoe is, indeed, inevitable...